# Displaying only visible in canvas features in attribute table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, filter, mapcanvas, select-by-expression

As explained by @xunilk in [Getting attribute values from vector features visible in QGIS canvas using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198607) we can easily access to the attribute values of the features visible in the QGIS canvas (code below)

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
rect = mapcanvas.extent()

request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(rect)

selected_feats = layer.getFeatures(request)

attr = [ feat.attributes() for feat in selected_feats ]

print(attr)
```

However I'm struggling to find a way to display, in the attribute table, only the values of the visible features.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why PyQgis? There is a standard keyboard shortcut for this: https://ibb.co/b3ZC5tL

Comment: because I have to implement this function in a plugin :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont know what can be done in plugins and not, but in QGIS you can apply a filter:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
rect = mapcanvas.extent()
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(rect)
selected_feats = layer.getFeatures(request)

ids = [f.id() for f in selected_feats]
where_clause = '"id" IN{0}'.format(tuple(ids))
layer.setSubsetString(where_clause)
```

Comment: Perfect @BERA that's exactly what I was looking for ! I just changed the ids variable with `ids = [f["target_field"] for f in selected_feats]` to match my need !

Answer (score 5):

This solution will open the attribute table with selected features within the canvas. It requires installation of the [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

```py
import pyautogui

layer = iface.activeLayer()

extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

layer.selectByRect(extent)

pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'F6')
```

---

This solution will create a new layer out of the selection within the canvas.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

layer.selectByRect(extent)

temp_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.selectedFeatureIds()))

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(temp_layer)
```

---

**References:**

- [Getting attributes of selected features using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31799/getting-attributes-of-selected-features-using-pyqgis/421263#421263)
- [Seeking keyboard shortcut in QGIS for opening attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227465/seeking-keyboard-shortcut-in-qgis-for-opening-attribute-table)

Comment: Thanks Taras for the detailled answer, it will be useful for another project of mine !